# Heroku - Deployment of Mongoose, Node.Js project throwing H10 error

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku, the project uses a Mongo Atlas database.

Below is the logs from Heroku when I try to run the application...

```
2020-05-12T14:34:05.889150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-12T14:34:05.892940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799472+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799493+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799493+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799494+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799494+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../helpers/document/handleSpreadDoc'
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799494+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799495+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799495+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799495+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799496+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799496+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799497+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799497+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799498+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799498+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799498+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799499+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799499+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799499+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js:6:25)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799500+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799501+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799501+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799501+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799502+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js:7:21)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799502+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799503+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799503+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799503+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799504+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799504+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799505+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799505+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799506+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799506+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799506+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799507+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799507+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799507+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799508+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-05-12T14:34:05.799508+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-05-12T14:34:12.433649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304011+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304033+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304033+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304033+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304034+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../helpers/document/handleSpreadDoc'
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304034+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304034+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304035+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304035+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304035+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304036+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304036+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304036+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304037+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304037+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304038+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js:6:25)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304039+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304039+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304039+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304040+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304040+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304040+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304041+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js:7:21)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304041+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304041+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304042+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304042+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14) {
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304042+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304043+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304043+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304043+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304044+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304044+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304044+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304045+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304045+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js',
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304045+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server.js'
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304045+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-05-12T14:34:12.304046+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-05-12T14:34:48.680452+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-coast-37017.herokuapp.com request_id=9b44f360-a32e-4175-a5de-e66d1df764c0 fwd="46.64.221.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-05-12T14:34:48.814619+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rocky-coast-37017.herokuapp.com request_id=0192bfaf-ab90-455e-b5a5-93844a134fa7 fwd="46.64.221.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Server.js...

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const app = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(express.static('node_modules'));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.S,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



let port = process.env.PORT;
if(port == null || port == "") {
    port = 3000;
}
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server has started');

//Database config

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://" + process.env.DB_Connection_User + ":" + process.env.DB_Connection_Password + "@cluster0-q4rxm.azure.mongodb.net/MerryBrew?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

//DB models


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    favourites: [{ cocktailName: String, cocktailImage: String }]
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//POSTS

app.post('/user/register', function (req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username }),
        req.body.password, function (err, account) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    err: err
                });
            }
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: 'Registration successful!'
                });
            });
        });
});


app.post('/user/login', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
                err: info
            });
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    err: 'Could not log in user'
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'Login successful!',
            });
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.post('/user/addFavourite', function (req, res) {
    let favourite = { "cocktailName": req.body.cocktailName, "cocktailImage": req.body.cocktailImage }
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.session.passport.user }, { $addToSet: { favourites: favourite } }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send("Failed to add favourite")
        } else
            return res.status(200).send("Added!")
    })
})

app.post('/user/deleteFavourite', function (req, res) {
    let favouriteToDelete = { "cocktailName": req.body.cocktailName }
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.session.passport.user }, { $pull: { favourites: favouriteToDelete } }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send("Failed to delete favourite")
        } else
            return res.status(200).send("Deleted!")
    })
})

//GETS

app.get('/user/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Bye!'
    });
});

app.get('/user/status', function (req, res) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(200).json({
            status: false
        });
    }
    res.status(200).json({
        status: true
    });
});

app.get('/user/getFavourites', function (req, res) {

    User.find({ username: req.session.passport.user }, 'favourites', function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send("Couldn't get favourites")
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(docs);
        }
    })
        .lean();
})
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "merrybrew",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cocktail Library",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Oliver Jacob",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.9",
    "angular-intro.js": "^3.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.7.9",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "fontawesome": "^5.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

I've got config vars set up on Heroku for everything that would otherwise be in a .env file.

Running the app locally it works without issue.

I've got the port defined as 3000 or the one that Heroku defines.

I've added the engines as the current node version to the package.json for the database side.

Procfile is correctly pointing at server.js.

So not sure what I'm missing here?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I removed the reference to require dotenv from the server.js, committed and re deployed, same error.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching, managed to fix this by clearing cached node modules from my repo, then doing a further commit and re deploying.